# ejabberd admin login error

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

After successfully installing ejabberd on windows 7, I am unable to login to the admin interface. I typed in the correct password but it still gives me authentication error. I have seen a number of posts online reporting this same problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add admin user with ejabberdctl and with ejabberd.cfg

NOTE: when you login you must write your jid(like adminUser@localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the name of the virtual domain that you manage: ex. admin@example.com?

Have you created the admin user with the command ejabberdctl?